# In the type definition for and_then where does the T come from?

Tags: rust

In Rust the [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) type has a method [`and_then()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then) which is defined as:

```rust
pub fn and_then<U, F>(self, f: F) -> Option<U>
where
    F: FnOnce(T) -> Option<U>,
```

I don't understand how I should read this type declaration. Where does the `T` come from? From context, I know that `T` is somehow related to the type contained by `self` but how do I know that from looking only at the type signature?

For comparison, Haskell's [`fmap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) function is defined as follows:

```hs
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

I *know* just by looking at the type signature that the type `a` which is passed to the first class function is contained in the input functor just by looking at the type signature.

Similarly, we could define `and_then` like

```hs
and_then :: Functor f => (a -> f b) -> f a -> f b
```

and things are similarly clear (to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` is the type argument to `Option`. It comes from the `impl<T> Option<T>` block that surrounds the method definitions. You can't tell from the method's type signature alone (which doesn't tell you what the type of `self` is) - you have to look at the surrounding `impl` as well.